# How to align label beside the textbox

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Please help me on this project. I want to align the Username and all the labels beside the textbox. Specifically on the left side of the textbox. I'm using the primary bootstrap from getbootstrap.com

[image]

This is my code:

```html
<div>
  <label>Username:</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" tabindex="1"><br>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" tabindex="2" float="right"><br>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Company Name" tabindex="3" float="right"><br>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Product Type" tabindex="4" float="right"><br>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't put it in a table. No need for that, bootstrap does this easily, and this isn't tabular data, so it's improper usage of the table element. https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/

Comment: are you using horizontal form? because this puts label on left side. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal

Comment: do you want a unique label by each input? Or you want all of these inputs beside a single label?

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried it, but it didn't work. Any other way to align it?

Comment: I add that if you have a placeholder for each field, you don't really need a label for them.

Comment: @Michael Coker, I want a unique label for each input

Comment: like this? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zwLdRg

Comment: looks great without the label imho. I would just leave it with the placeholders

Comment: Not ADA compliant without labels.  You can put them in there and then hide them, but they do have to exist: https://www.w3.org/WAI/tutorials/forms/labels/

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the form-horizontal class for the form.  Also, I noticed your inputs didn't have any name attributes, which I'm assuming you'll need.  Documentation: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="username" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username" tabindex="1" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="password" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password" tabindex="2" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="company_name" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Company Name</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="company_name" placeholder="Company Name" tabindex="3" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="product_type" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Product Type</label>
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="product_type" placeholder="Product Type" tabindex="4" />
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```